# how can i delete a file or folder on github?

Tags: git, github, directory, delete-file

I created a folder by mistake in name of it, and now I want to delete this folder or the file that is inside the folder. When I go to relevant folder and try this command `git rm -r Data Development` (Data Development is the name of my folder),  I faced with this error:

`fatal: pathspec 'data' did not match any files`

How can I delete this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes `Data` and `Development` as two different command-line arguments. Quote it to make it one.

```
git rm -r "Data Development"
```